# Why am I not getting the right answer for this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, electromagnetism

I'm trying to solve the integral below. I'm not getting the right answer no matter what. Can you tell me why my method is wrong? I'm applying the rule for integrating $x^n$ (i.e. $\smash{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}$). Why it's not working? (ditch $\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi$ if it confuses you)

> $$\large{\begin{align}
> \vec{\mathbf{B}}&=\frac{\mu_0I\rho}{4\pi}\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{[\rho^2+z^2]^{3/2}}\,\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi \\
> &=\frac{\mu_0I\rho}{4\pi}\left[\frac b{\sqrt{\rho^2+b^2}}-\frac a{\sqrt{\vphantom{b^2}\rho^2+a^2}}\right]\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi
> \end{align}}$$

#### My work:

\begin{align}
\vec{\mathbf{B}}&=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_a^b\frac{I\rho\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z^2+\rho^2)^{3/2}}\,\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi \\[10pt]
&=\frac{\mu_0I\rho}{4\pi}\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z^2+\rho^2)^{3/2}}\,\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi \\[10pt]
&=\frac{-2\mu_0I\rho}{4\pi}\bigg[(z^2+\rho^2)^{-1/2}\bigg]_a^b\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi \\[10pt]
&=\frac{\mu_0I\rho}{2\pi}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{b^2+\rho^2}}-\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+\rho^2}}\right)\vec{\mathbf{a}}_\phi
\end{align}

Comment: Where is the minus sign from $-1/2\pi$? And if $\vec a_\phi$ is just a constant you missed it. Please use $\LaTeX$ to write math.

Comment: @manooooh a⃗ϕ is just showing in which direction will the resultant scalar be.

Comment: @MMM I edited your question to include MathJax formatting; see [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for instructions on how to use MathJax for yourself. It's easy to pick up, don't worry!

Comment: @RobertHoward Thanks man, I'll make sure I use it next time

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2+\alpha^2)^{3/2}} dx= \frac{x}{\alpha^2\sqrt{x^2+\alpha^2}}+c$$

Comment: ok but why applying the x^n rule is wrong to apply here?

Comment: @MMM Because the $z$ that appears when you use the chain rule to find the derivative of $(\rho^2-z^2)^{-1/2}$ doesn’t appear in the integrand.